# Wireshark and promiscous mode

Tags: wireshark

I am using Wireshark for class. Does Wireshark put your card in promiscuous mode automatically, or must you manually do it?  I've searched everywhere I can, and cannot find the answer. I have it running in a virtual machine, and when I set the virtual machine promiscuous mode I'm not sure if that means I'm actually putting the card in such a mode, or just enabling the ability to put it in such mode.  Basically I'm not sure if the virtual machine setting is turning on promiscuous or Wireshark.

Comment: Yes, the wireshark will automatically put the card in promiscuous mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wireshark automatically puts the card into promiscuous mode.

Optionally, this can be disabled by using the -p parameter in the command line, or via a checkbox in the GUI:

Capture > Options > Capture packets in promiscuous mode